I want to understand the meaning behind my grandmothers and my moms Korean name
명길 - my halmuni’s name
영박 - my mother’s same
I’ve researched this years back and have learned they are both “male” names. The internet is inconsistent and I can’t seem to locate the information I had before.
My mom is weird with me asking questions like this and never will give me a straight answer.

명길 is also used as a woman's name. 최명길 is a great actress, for example.
but yeah, both 명길 and 영박 "generally" sound like a man's name.
Regarding the meanings of the names, we need their Chinese characters.
Most of the Koreans' names use Chinese characters.
If you can show me the Chinese characters of the names, I will be able to answer your question about the meanings of the names.
